# e.Dismiss() does not work in ErrorLog_Filtering method in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am trying to stop errors from reaching my error collection but I am unable to.

```
public void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Dismiss();
}
```

The errors still reach my error collection and I don't know why. I placed breakpoints and the method works, e.Dismiss() gets called.
Any ideas? I'm all out.

Comment: Maybe publish your web.config? Could be that you are not registering the ErrorFilter module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was happening. Someone else added a global filter that was handling the exceptions and logging them to the error collection.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LogExceptionFilter());
    }
```

and inside the LogExceptionFilter:

```
 public class LogExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            _log.Error(context.Exception);            
        }

        private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.Instance.GetLogger();
    }
```